# upload wordpress post and related images

Tags: excel, wordpress, post, import

i am trying to upload a batch of posts from an excel to wordpress.
the data does not have xml format, just is plain text. In other hand, exist at least 4 image per post.

awaiting for comments!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import large spreadsheets of data using [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/). It is a paid plugin but it is well worth the price tag IMO if you are going to be doing this often. Simple drag and drop interface and walks you through everything step-by-step.